# How host name is translated to IP Address when the DNS server is turned off?

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, dns

I have several virtual machines on virtual box with windows 7 installed and one has windows server 2012 which is acting as domain controller and DNS.

When I turn that Windows Server off which was listed as a DNS server for each of the other virtual machines, I am still able to access other systems by their host name.

I want to know how this resolution works in the absence of a DNS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name resolution is done through the Windows Internet Name Service ([WINS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Internet_Name_Service)).

From Wikipedia:

> Windows Internet Name Service (WINS) is Microsoft's implementation of NetBIOS Name Service (NBNS), a name server and service for NetBIOS computer names. Effectively, WINS is to NetBIOS names what DNS is to domain names — a central mapping of host names to network addresses. Like DNS, it is implemented in two parts, a Server Service (that manages the embedded Jet Database, server to server replication, service requests, and conflicts) and a TCP/IP Client component which manages the client's registration and renewal of names, and takes care of queries.

This allows machines on the same network to communicate with each other by hostname without DNS.

Also, if the machines were accessed before DNS was taken offline, Windows will cache DNS entries until the entries are flushed.  Caches DNS entries will persist till they are manually flushed (`ipconfig /flushdns`) or a reboot.

These dont apply to your case, however its good to know:

- DNS entries can be cached by browsers as well
- Name resolution can be done through the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file.

Comment: What about simple "caching" if those systems have been previously accessed?

Comment: @w3d Good point, I forgot about that.  I will add that to the answer.

Comment: The odds are very slim that OPs Windows Server 2012 has WINS enabled without their knowledge.  MS stopped enabling it by default in Server 2003 or earlier, so you'd have to purposefully setup a WINS server and distribute it's address via DHCP.  They are MUCH more likely to be resolving via a cache, NetBIOS or even Hosts files, IMO. :)

Comment: Even after I reboot the two windows 7 VMs, and the server is turned off, (which means cache must have been flushed), the ping for hostname on command line resolves. I have also read somewhere that ping uses DNS and not WINS.

Comment: @teenup then its resolving using NetBIOS

Comment: NetBios is different from WINS?